# How to make TextInput cursorDelegate wider + taller

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to style the cursorDelegate on a TextArea/TextInput so that it ends up taller and thicker than the default one?

With the following code, I can currently get one that has the following properties:

1. Thicker than normal, at 4px wide
2. Taller than the rest of the text, with bits sticking out above/below the line as wanted. BUT, this only works until the user moves the cursor. Then, the vertical size gets clipped again, and can't be reset.

```cpp
TextArea {
  id: editor
  cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
    width: 4
    
    property int vpad: 4

    y: editor.cursorRectangle.y - (vpad / 2)
    height: editor.cursorRectangle.height + vpad
  }
}
```

It looks like the y and height bindings are getting overwritten by whatever sets those automatically internally.

Trying to overwrite these again myself using a onCursorPositionChanged handler on the TextArea fails, as you cannot write to cursorDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a solution. Instead of setting these values in the normal way, you need to set these on the change handlers for those properties.

```
TextArea {
  id: editor
  cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
    width: 4
    
    property int vpad: 4

    onYChanged: y = editor.cursorRectangle.y - (vpad / 2)
    onHeightChanged: height = editor.cursorRectangle.height + vpad
  }
}
```

This seems to resist the widgets auto behaviour that was overwriting our values.

Related details from Qt Docs:

> The position and height of a custom cursorDelegate are updated to
> follow the cursorRectangle automatically when it changes. The width of
> the delegate is unaffected by changes in the cursor rectangle.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#cursorRectangle-prop